# Magento cloud limitations

Tags: magento2

We have few queries related to cloud features, Infra and support to get clarity on it.  Could someone help review and provide answers for below queries.  Thanks in advance.

1. Can we restrict ssh connectivity based on IP in cloud?
2. Is cloud default support auto scale feature(scaling - vertical / horizontal scaling), if not how to upgrade server to support traffic(scaling - vertical / horizontal scaling)?
3. Maximum number of domains can be mapped to cloud single instance, Is there any limitation on no. of domains it supports on cloud server ( like create virtual hosts and IP map to domains)
4. What are the limitations if we want to sync Amazon orders to the magento cloud through any available extensions or AWS
   API's?
5. Is there are any limitation on number of api requests to ERP/CRM systems?
   Does it supports integrating system with other cms systems like drupal, wordpress etc.
6. Are there any limitation of out going / incoming request like fedex, paypal , third party mail campaign systems etc.

Comment: magento cloud is managed service - ask them directly...

Answer (score 0):

**1 - Can we restrict ssh connectivity based on IP in cloud?**
SSH access and Magento Deployment environments are not restricted to IPs by default however is only accessible for specific users, for that users are created in Magento Cloud Interface and add public-key of their accounts.

**2 - Is cloud default support auto scale feature(scaling - vertical / horizontal scaling), if not how to upgrade server to support traffic(scaling - vertical / horizontal scaling)?**

You can't upscale or downscale your servers, yourselves. you have to notify Magento Team / your Project Account Manager for any upcoming spike ( 48hrs before any upcoming event ) where you mention date time and how long this spike will last.

**3 - Maximum number of domains can be mapped to cloud single instance, Is there any limitation on no. of domains it supports on cloud server ( like create virtual hosts and IP map to domains)**

You can map upto 5 domains with single license. however your core will remain same so its like 5 sites with 5 stores having same source code.

**4 - What are the limitations if we want to sync Amazon orders to the magento cloud through any available extensions or AWS API's?**

There are not any limitations, but can confirm from your account manager.

**5 - Is there are any limitation on number of api requests to ERP/CRM systems? Does it supports integrating system with other cms systems like drupal, wordpress etc.**

No there is not any limitation.

**6 - Are there any limitation of out going / incoming request like fedex, paypal , third party mail campaign systems etc.**

No there are not any specific, however there is monthly email quota which you can ask from magento team to increase in case you feel it will be exceeded.

---

Hope i have answered all questions, if there is any feel free to comment or update your question.